# Where do Wikitext questions belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As the question suggests I am wondering where Wikitext questions belong, if they belong on any of the sites offered.

My basic question is concerning formatting a multi-line block of text inside of a list using Wikitext.

I have searched through the web and could not find an answer, so I figured the best place to ask would be on the relevant stack.

Considering the options:

**Stack Overflow**:
My question isn't related to programming.  Instead it is about formatting of Wikitext.  Most of the questions and answers on SO seem to be about parsing Wikitext and not about using it.

**Server Fault**:
No.  This question has nothing to do with servers.

**Super User** (SU):
Seems to be a catch-all for questions, but no one else seems to have posted anything about Wikitext, and Super User (Stack Exchange site) says its purpose is:

> If you have a question about …
>
> ```
> * computer hardware
> * computer software
> ```

Of which my question is neither.

**DocType**:
My question is about Wikitext, which is on the web, but not related to CS/HTML, which is what most of the questions on DocType seem to be about (0 matches for a search of 'Wikitext').

Where should I post such a question?  Or is there somewhere I can post this question? Should I try going to a Wiki specific site, outside of the Stack Exchange universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SU is probably closest out of the trilogy, but they're fairly anti web-application questions. You probably want to ask on the [Web Applications SE site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), which is in public beta at the moment

Comment: Hmm.. This could be a possibility, but most of the questions on this site seem to be more about locating various web applications for specific purposes or determining which one to use than actually using one.  For my question, I have a specific example of what I am doing (my markup), and why it does not work, which looking at the current questions doesn't seem to quite match.  It might be worth a shot though.

Comment: @KLee1: Using web apps is the intend of this site, although many people are just asking for recommendations.

Comment: @neo Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

Questions about **using** web applications that use [WikiText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wikitext) like Wikipedia are on-topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

"Questions" about content, protocols, disputes between users, are not. They should directly handle through the respective channels that Wikipedia has for such topics.

---

Asking for web applications recommendation removed from the scope. IIRC this was after the graduation of [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

---

Related

- [Where do MediaWiki questions belong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62131/289691)
- [Where to ask Wikipedia usage-related question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246062/289691)
- [Where would I ask a historical question about Wikipedia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296837/289691)
- [Where do I ask a question about a specific case regarding Wikipedia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375409/289691)