# Where do MediaWiki questions belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about MediaWiki formatting. Since this is similar to LaTeX questions, I figured it would have a nice, happy home on Stack Overflow. I'm not quite sure if it's programmer related enough though.

What does the community think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask and answer MediaWiki questions on StackOverflow. There was once a  [WikiSpeedia proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) on Area 51, which would have been the ideal place... =:-)

Comment: @George - thanks for accepting. Do you want to follow WikiSpeedia as well? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia