# Where on Stack Exchange should I ask my questions about MediaWiki?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions about many things in MediaWiki. In *which site* should I post my questions?

Comment: Really depends a *lot* on what sorts of things you're doubting.

Comment: @Shog9: What about this (http://superuser.com/questions/833758/mediawiki-uploading-tables-of-extension-via-browser) question? I have asked 3 questions about mediawiki in Superuser but received nothing as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do MediaWiki questions belong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62131/where-do-mediawiki-questions-belong)

Answer (score 6):

If your question is about using MediaWiki from *the perspective of a user*, [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki) is probably okay.

If your question is about *setup, configuration, customization, or other topics of concern to an owner/administrator*, it looks like [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki) would be a good fit.

(Both of those sites have about an equal number of questions with that tag as [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki), so it looks like maybe your questions are okay where they are.)

As always, check the site's *Help Center* before posting. You can always ask on a site's Meta (or chat) if your question would be on-topic. (Assuming, of course, you have enough Reputation to do so.)

Comment: Actually, the OP won't have the association bonus, so they might not be able to ask on that site's meta.

Comment: @Scimonster: Chat either, I suppose. Well, there's always "trial by fire".

Comment: I've been told that questions about creating templates are not on-topic at Web Apps: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120176/best-practices-for-including-wikipedia-templates-on-outside-wiki/120178#comment108682_120176

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a [Wikis.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79413/wikis?referrer=wuY59ZBbDdFS2USK7BR8zQ2), but it's in early stages of definition. If that ever makes it into a site, it would probably be on topic there.

But until then, you should follow [Fish Below the Ice's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275804/3187556).

Comment: The Wiki.SE proposal has since been deleted.