# Where to ask Wikipedia usage-related question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question related to using a website [wikipedia.org](http://wikipedia.org). It is a question related to how to use this website (specifically I would like to ask how I can easily get the number of reviews of an article - which I relate to its relative reliability).

I was thinking that this could maybe connected with superuser.com
which encourages to ask about

> Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking

considering that with some reason one might say that Wikipedia is software, especially the specific aspect I wonder about (i.e., *how to get the review count of an article?*)

I would be happy to get feedback regarding this, or as the tag suggests a site-recommendation.

Also, as an additional aspect to this question: Is the correct next step to ask in meta.superuser.com for "is this a valid/acceptable question?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly, there are a ton of people helping out at the [Help Desk at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk). That's where I would go if I had a question about Wikipedia.

If you really want a Stack Exchange site, then [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikipedia) is your best bet.

Comment: I like both concepts, wikipedia's and SE and for asking questions I am liking the structure SE gives much more than ordinary forums, so I will try out Web Applications. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can ask at [Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Stackexchange