# Where to make suggestions for popular services?

Tags: support, area-51, site-recommendation

Suppose I have a query, complaint (with possible improvements) or suggestion (pertaining to bugs or design and features) for an popular service or software, ranging from Microsoft Excel to Facebook Chat. Where can I ask such questions? Is there a site on the network dedicated to such questions? (I couldn't find any.) If not, shall I just ask on Stack Overflow, or should I go to Area 51 and wait till such a site is made?

Comment: Wouldn't it be most effective if those were directly send to the owner of such sites?

Comment: @rene I tried that with Facebook, as well as Microsoft. Microsoft didn't even bother to respond, and Facebook gave a simple answer that they would look into it (and did nothing about it). Also, I would like experts who are willing, to discus why the suggestions are right or wrong, rather than just a yes or no. SE seems a good place for doing so.

Comment: And then what would happen if the *experts* say **YES**. Would that change the outcome of the issue?

Comment: If you take a look on MSE itself, how many [tag:bug] and [tag:feature-request] posts are open. More often than not it is not the request itself that is unreasonable but the sheer amount of other request as well. The backlog is always bigger than the number of resources you have.

Comment: `with possible improvements`, `pertaining to bugs or design and features`, My question Who would help in improvement? It is something like Say you have a car and it has fault, rather than taking to it's manufacturing center for defect correction, you discuss about the topic somewhere in some corner where no one will help you and there will be only discussions and discussions.

Comment: @MetaWonder I think the OP imagines an off-site discussion where consensus is reached among many instead of one person. If a post seems to reached agreement only then it is send to the vendors. Basically the OP is looking for or want to create a site that organizes individual users into a group of users with shared interests/goals.

Comment: @rene Right but that would not be constructive.

Comment: @MetaWonder Yes, rene is right about what I am asking. Why wouldn't it be constructive? There must be people wanting to know the pros and cons of each other's suggestions, that they themselves never thought of. Whether or not those actual sites even want to know that such discussions take place is a different question altogether.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246062/where-to-ask-wikipedia-usage-related-question/246064#246064) question and see the answer from user [AI.E](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246063/275802).If one has to know the pros and cons then there are already places like that in SE superuser for computer related, Askubuntu for linux related. And from @rene's answer `And then what would happen if the experts say YES. Would that change the outcome of the issue?`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nowhere.

Stack Exchange is not the place to send through your feature requests, bug reports or re-design improvement suggestions for any other website or web app beyond Stack Exchange. No matter what those other places try and tell you.

For those other sites, Facebook, Google, etc., you need to contact them directly. If those sites do not get back to you, or make it hard to even leave such feedback, it's because they don't want to hear about it.

For questions about *using* a web app like Facebook, Outlook.com, or Google Hangouts, then [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is your place.

Comment: I am not looking for those other sites to know about our discussions. I am just looking for a place where such suggestions and improvements could be discussed.

Comment: If a particular suggestion is obviously a good one, then SE has nothing to do with whether it is accepted by the other brand or not. If you do not know for sure that it is a good one, or feel that it is controversial, people should have an option of discussing it on SE.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code That's not what SE is here for.  It is not a discussion platform, it is a question and answer platform.  It actively avoids having posts like that.  There are plenty of other sites in the world where you can hold meaningless discussions about whatever you want if you're just looking to entertain yourself talking with other people.

Answer (score 8):

[OP’s comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247937/where-to-ask-suggestions-for-popular-services#comment812300_247937):

> I would like experts who are willing, to discus why the suggestions are right or wrong, rather than just a yes or no.

If the issue is about the **user experience** of the web app, you could ask such a question on [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). This is *not* for reporting issues to the web app owners, but for discussing the issue and possible solutions/alternatives (e.g.: good/bad usability? could it be done better? if yes, how?).
Example question: [YouTube automatically switches to “Share” tab when the video is finished playing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/42849/17023)

(If it were *your* web app, you could ask for a **design** critique on [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) and for a **code** review on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).)

As a user:

- If you want a **workaround** for an issue that affects you, you could ask on [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).
- If you look for **alternative** services, you could ask on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -4):

For the first part of your question:

Queries on web applications to [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Queries on computer applications to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not sure if you read the question properly. The OP would like to report bugs in the software that he's using -- *that* has no place on SE.

Comment: @Shokhet, I was only answering they very first part of his question that dealt with queries, not the other part which is answered well in the other answers. this part -> "Suppose I have a query".