# Where would I ask a historical question about Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site where I could ask questions about events in Wikipedia's history?

To clarify, I'm aware I can ask technical questions on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I'm looking to ask a more historical question. Specifically, "*Was the [2011 Wikimedia Image Filter](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Image_filter_referendum/en) ever implemented?*"

I tried [searching online](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wikimedia%20Foundation%20image%20filter), but unfortunately couldn't find much discussion about whether the filter was ever put in place.

Comment: For those interested, I found an interesting article about the proposed Wikimedia Image Filter titled [*The Dispute over Filtering "Indecent" Images in Wikipedia*](https://journals.muni.cz/mujlt/article/download/2638/2202)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of March 2023 I don't think that Web Applications is an appropiate place to ask historical questions about a web application as nowadays we (I'm a mod in Web Applications) have a close reason for questions that asks about internal policies, technologies, among other stuff, pointing the OP to [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163).

In Web Applications questions should be focused on **using** the web application as is currently offered by the developer / official operator. Questions about self hosted web applications that were customized are off-topic. Questions about using the out-of-the-box components might be on-topic while they work per the developer documentation for end-users.

Questions about open-source code projects (i.e. MediaWiki) other that *using* it as end-user, and [systems developement lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) / [software development process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)  are off-topic.

Related from Web Applications Meta

- [Do we need a close reason for questions asking about proprietary/non-public information or policies?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4614/88163)

Answer (score 2):

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) would be the appropriate place in Stack Exchange to ask.

But, honestly, I'd ask at [The Village pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump). There's a *huge* community of people who bang away on Wikipedia; they'll be the best people to ask. (I don't see much overlap with Stack Exchange.)