# Where do I ask a question about a specific case regarding Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I first tried asking the following question on the *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)* site. The question was closed as opinion-based on that site. [I asked what I can do on the meta site. I was told that the question is not a good fit for Web Applications, because it is about a specific case related to competency rules rather than using Wikipedia](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/how-can-i-edit-my-question-that-was-closed-as-opinion-based/4852#4852). So, on what site could I ask a question such as the following?

> What steps do I take if I am indefinitely site-banned on Wikipedia?
>
> My Wikipedia user page is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Neel.arunabh. Unfortunately, I have been banned indefinitely by the community with a discussion at [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=1066833242#Neel.arunabh's_competence_issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=1066833242#Neel.arunabh%27s_competence_issues). An "indefinite" block is not an "infinite" block. So, what steps can I take so that I will be allowed to resume to Wikipedia?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Wikipedia people?

Comment: This is like asking Ebay how to fix an issue on Amazon or asking Samsung how to fix your Apple phone

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya - Let me clear. We cannot help you get unbanned from Wikipedia. However, I find it hilarious that someone indicated that an indefinite ban is not an infinite ban since the literally meaning of the word is unlimited.  The literal meaning of infinite is limitless.  Your question is not within scope on any SE community at this time.  Appeal your ban, but based on your actions I doubt that will happen. **Don’t reply to this comment, I won’t reply, and will flag any response from you as unnecessary** I find your actions at Wikipedia personally deplorable.

Comment: The referenced Wikipedia process does not inspire a lot of confidence - *"This behavior raises concerns about both English-language comprehension and potentials for copyright infringement in mainspace. ... abusive sockpuppetry ... disastrous attempts to fix things, like "fixing" reference errors by deleting references and content from articles ... once again display a poor command of English to the point that it interferes with his ability to make or understand arguments ... can't express simple thoughts in your own words"*

Comment: It is not much better here on Stack Exchange. [From the Spanish language meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4444) site: [Plagiarised question on *Spanish*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39967/are-there-consistent-rules-for-pronouncing-c-j-s-x-and-z) (of [this one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/are-there-consistent-rules-for-pronouncing-c-and-g)). ***And that was only about one month ago***. Perhaps it is time to drop [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) from your toolbox? Yes, that is a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This question is about the inner-workings of another community (Wikipedia), and probably won't be a good fit anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Wikipedia itself has a few resources about [appealing bans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Banning_policy#Appeals_of_bans_imposed_by_the_community), I assume that would be a good place to start.